# SQL Server - Updating strategy

Tags: sql-server

I'm relatively new to sql server and I have successfully installed it in my testing environment. I'm also using Icigina2 for the internal monitoring. Icinga2 is reporting me if there are available updates for windows server itself.

At windows updates I have enabled the option

> Receive updates for other Microsoft products when you update Windows

But I haven’t received any updates for sql-server until now. I'm really wondering about this, because normally Microsoft releases tons of updates for all their products. But I'm remebering that I have seen updates for sql-server via windows updates somewhere at customers who have sql-server express.

I have checked my sql-server version

> Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-GDR) (KB4517790) - 15.0.2070.41

If I'm right I have the GDR1 from November 2019. But there are a lot of cumulative updates. Windows Update isn't showing me any of these updates. But I can't imagine that there isn't any security related CU-Update (CU1-CU8).

But is there the only way to manually look on the Microsoft page? I'm fine with it to install the updates manually. But I would like to have an automatic report/alert within my icinga2-monitoring. I don't like the way to manually check a website for available updates...

Are there any settings for windows updates missing? I was also not able to find a icinga2-script which would check for avaiable sql server updates...

Answer (score -1):

SQL Server updates - service packs and the CU packs (Cumulative Updates) are plentyfull. If you do not get them, something is off - most likely you get your updates from a WSUS server that is just not configured to offer SQL Server updates. Install directly from Microsoft. There are plenty. SQL Server: check https://buildnumbers.wordpress.com/sqlserver/ for a list of all build numbers. Last is    CU8 – 15.0.4073.23

Comment: **If you do not get them, something is off.....** this is the reason why I'm asking. I know that I can do this manually (directly downloading from microsoft). But as I have explained that's not what I want. I don't have a WSUS server. I'm just receiving windows updates the default way.